# objects are not crated through cmd django python

Tags: python, django

```
>>> from sabin.models import Task
>>> Task.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> t=Task(title="dhiraj")
```

error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\ero\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
line 503, in **init** raise TypeError
("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.**name**, kwarg))
TypeError: Task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
title:models.CharField(max_length=200)
completed=models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Share your `Task` model.

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Comment: You have a `:` instead of a `=`. `title = models.CharField(...)`

Answer (score 3):

You used a colon (`:`) to specify a `CharField`, but you should use an equals sign, so:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    #     ↓ do not use a colon :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # …
```